# Error in modCost(obs = world_data, model = out) : object 'world_data' not found in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compile the following code. It's a code for model calibration for system dynamics models.

It gives me the following error.

**Error in modCost(obs = world_data, model = out) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**

**The problem seems to emerge in modCost function.**. Please help. Code as follows.

Input file can be downloaded from here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ubl5lm5wo8qngz/WorldPopulation.xlsx?dl=0

```
library(deSolve)
library(gdata)
library(FME)
library(readxl)

WorldPopulation <- read_excel("C:/Users/nikhi/Documents/WorldPopulation.xlsx")
world_data<-WorldPopulation

#simulation time
START<-1960; FINISH<- 2010;STEP<-0.1
simtime<-seq(START, FINISH, by = STEP)
WP_INIT <- 3026002942

#defining the model function (stock and flow equations)
model<-function(time, stocks, auxs){

  with(as.list(c(stocks, auxs)),{

    fPopulationAdded <- Population * aGrowthFraction

    dP_dt <- fPopulationAdded

    return(list(c(dP_dt)))
  })
}

#calling it under a funrction to solve the equation
solveWP<- function(pars){

  stocks<- c(Population = WP_INIT)

  auxs<-c(aGrowthFraction = unname((pars["aGrowthFraction"])))

  return(data.frame(ode(y=stocks, simtime, func = model, parms = auxs, method = "euler")))
}

#calculating cost (deviation from the actual data)
getCost<-function(p)
{
  out<- solveWP(p)
  cost <- modCost(obs = world_data, model = out)
  return (cost)
}

#definining parametrs to be optimized
pars<-c(aGrowthFraction = 0.001)
lower<-c(0.0)
upper <- c(0.2)

#run optimizer

Fit<- modFit(p = pars, f= getCost, lower = lower, upper = upper)  #Error appears here. 

optPar <- c(Fit$par)
```

Comment: First set `world_data <- as.data.frame(WorldPopulation)` and in `solveWP` use `return(ode(y=stocks, simtime, func = model, parms = auxs, method = "euler"))`

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thanks @MarcoSandri.  I just want to understand it though. When we read an excel file, by default isn't it a data. frame format. Also, now since we have removed data.frame from the return function in SolveWP, doesn't it make like two different types of argument going in modCost function.

Comment: You are right, `read_excel` returns a so-called `tibble` that is not 100 percent compatible to a `data.frame`. Let me add a few notes: (1) why do you use "euler"? If we assume that the number of people is high and they reproduce more or less permanently, I would use a continuous solver, e.g. "lsoda" or "adams". (2) then you could also integrate analytically with an exponential growth function. (3) package **growthrates** has all this built-in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I used Euler because that is usually standard practice for "System Dynamics" methods. All the equations are written keeping the "Euler" integration in mind.  But I will also explore the other options that you have highlighted. Here it is a simple equation, which can be easily approximated with an exponential function. But in other cases, it may not be so.